# variable in .js file wont keep value for AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

the variable 'output' is not keeping its value

```
function send()
{
var output;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    output = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

**This output displays 'hello world'**

```
alert(output);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",'mp.php',true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

**This output displays 'Undefined':**

```
alert(output);
return output
}
```

the contents of mp.php displays 'Hello world' when navigated to in browser

How do i make the output variable not 'Undefined' when returning it?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is Asynchronous.

What's happening in your code is

1. Setup `XMLHttpRequest`
2. Print `Output` \\ undefined
3. Asynchronous call is successful
4. Print `Output` \\ "Hello World"

To fix this, in your success method, call a new method that prints Output

Answer (score 2):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. The flow of your code is like this:

```
xmlhttp.send(); // async, so program flow will continue
alert(output); // this happened BEFORE the ajax call returned, so it is undefined here.
```

A better approach would be to use callbacks when your ajax call completes. The callback can do whatever you need to do with the value returned from the ajax call.

On a related note, you might find it easier to work with jquery. You can simplify it to

```
$.get('myurl',{
  success: function(res) { // do success function }
});
```

Comment: If i put return where the successful alert is, it still does not return anything, so what do i do to fix it?

Comment: You don't actually return a value from the success method. Instead your success action would be to call another method that acts on the return value.

Comment: Ok, so if i was to use this code:
    `var o = send;`
How would i get the return to the variable 'o'

Comment: In your example above (in the question), where you call `alert(output)`, change that to `yourMoreComplexFunction(output)`, and then `yourMoreComplexFunction` would have access to `output`

Comment: I am still completely stumped, can you please give me an example?

Comment: I'm unclear what's causing you issues...can you explain? In your example where you call `alert` to dispaly the variable, you can call any function there. You don't return the value from the success callback, you just pass it to the function you want to call (in the current code, that is `alert` but can be anything you want).

Answer (score 0):

Theres no return. Delegate (.onreadystatechange=function()) runs out of your functions (send()). There's three ways: a) define global variable output and use it; b) run xttpRequest syncroniously (with no events and event-handling); c) change structure of your code to handle success event.